# Slow ASP.NET site using IIS6

Tags: iis-6, asp.net

I have two servers, one virtual and one physical, running the exact same site on both machines.

Both machines are running on ~ 2% CPU load and very much RAM available for usage.

Somehow the site, with cache turned off ofcourse, loads in ~ 500ms on the virtual machine (which is a dev-server by the way) but almost 3 full seconds on the physical machine.

They're both running Server 2003, IIS6 aswell as asp.net version 2.0

Any ideas where I can start troubleshoot this?

Best Regards
LP

Answer (score 0):

- Could you please describe shortly what is the site about? What actions does it take to load up the home page? IS it DB access or whatever?
- What are the differences between the sites besides for VM/physical box? Are they using the same data source? If no, might it be the data source slowness?
- In any case, it's a good idea to use a profiling tool to find out what's the site spending these 3 seconds for. VSTS, ANTS, JetBrains dotTrace, YourKit - any will do.

Comment: * It's a full homepage but it's one script which resizes images on-the-fly _every_ time the page is loaded (I do know that the script is useless but that's another issue.
* They're both set up as different machines, one for lab and one for hosting. The hosting one, which also is the physical one, is the slow one - I've been tracing both I/O / CPU / RAM and none of 'em are barely moving at all, so I'm pretty sure it ain't any datasource slowness. They do not share data source.
* I'll give them a try!

Comment: Each site also has a "personal" application pool with identical settings on both machines.

Comment: I've ran each site through FireBug aswell too verify that it's that particular script that's slow, it's not a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this particular issue and made the developers rebuild their site instead since it was pretty much useless and had more leaks the Julian Assange, sorry for bothering you.